# need max value from sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a view which has many columns including  ID,home, year,player,resource  in it. I want to pull unique home records having only maximum value in year column.

Below is the data from view and expected output.

**Data**

```
id  home  year     player   resource
---|-----|------|--------|---------
1  | 10  | 2009 | john   | 399 
2  | 11  | 2007 | juliet | 244
5  | 12  | 2009 | borat  | 555
3  | 10  | 2010 | john   | 300
4  | 11  | 2009 | juliet | 200
6  | 12  | 2008 | borat  | 500
7  | 13  | 2004 | borat  | 600
8  | 13  | 2009 | borat  | 700
```

**Expected output** (unique home records having max year)

```
id  home  year     player   resource
---|-----|------|--------|---------
5  | 12  | 2009 | borat  | 555
3  | 10  | 2010 | john   | 300
4  | 11  | 2009 | juliet | 200
8  | 13  | 2009 | borat  | 700
```

Please suggest best way to do it.

Comment: `Max`, `Group By` and a minimum amount of effort

Comment: Can you at least give us your table schema and the fields you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry about that, i have updated above question

Comment: Downvoted because: It seems you are not the first one with exactly this homework (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1) and you did not even try to program anything or to search.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT home, MAX(year) AS year FROM Table1 GROUP BY home
)
SELECT * FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN cte ON a.home = cte.home AND a.year = cte.year
```

Live demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/678771/8/0